# Is the Sqlite file included in the submission to App Store?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am developing my first application for iOS. I use data I uploaded in the Sqlite Db using core data.
I would like to know if the Sqlite file is included in the generated Archive file by Xcode, if not, how to have these data available in the final application in app store ?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include the database as part of the other resources just like any other resource.  Note, however, that it will be read-only, and you can only use it as a read-only database for searching, or for seeding a read-write database.